# Pass object inside of nested promise

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a chained promise. Inside of the first promise I have an object I need inside of the last promise as well. How can I pass this object within the chained promise? **Is there a better practice than storing the value with `let home;`?**

```
let home;
return this.httpGetHome(name).then(result => {
  home = result[0];
  return result[0];
}).then(result => {
  return this.httpGetOwner(result.owner);
}).then((result: any) => {
  const owner = Characters.default.find(char => char.name === result.name);
  return {...home, owner};
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that situation, you'd usually *nest* your fulfillment handler so it has access to the value:

```
return this.httpGetHome(name).then(result => {
  return result[0];
}).then(home => {
  return this.httpGetOwner(home.owner)
    .then((result: any) => {
      const owner = Characters.default.find(char => char.name === result.name);
      return {...home, owner};
  });
});
```

But based on your use of `home` at the end, it must not be a promise, which means there's no reason for separate `then` handlers initially:

```
return this.httpGetHome(name).then(([home]) => { // Note the destructuring
  return this.httpGetOwner(home.owner)
    .then((result: any) => {
      const owner = Characters.default.find(char => char.name === result.name);
      return {...home, owner};
  });
});
```

Or in modern environments you could use an `async` function and then use `await` within it:

```
// In an `async` function
const [home] = await this.httpGetHome(name); // Note the destructuring
const result = await this.httpGetOwner(home.owner);
const owner = Characters.default.find(char => char.name === result.name);
return {...home, owner};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like this

```js
return this.httpGetHome(name).then(([home]) => {
  return Promise.all([this.httpGetOwner(home.owner), home]);
}).then(([result, home]) => {
  const owner = Characters.default.find(char => char.name === result.name);
  return { ...home, owner };
});
```